# Do Women Look at Fingers for Havdala?

Tags: minhag, women, havdalah

At least in some communities, women haven't been seen looking at their fingers during havdala for the bracha on fire. ([Badei Hashulchan (96:12)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7722&st=&pgnum=132&hilite=) – לא ראיתי שנשים יביטו בצפרנים אחר בומ״ה) Is it just me or do most women look at their fingers during havdala?

Comment: VTC as Opinion Based?

Comment: @dou, opinion? It's asking for stats.

Comment: @msh is asking for what everyone's impression is considered statistics? Maybe if he clarified what kind of statistics he'd accept as an answer

Comment: He explains the reason why maybe they dont because they were the cause of not being covered in a nail covering.  However ,al pi pshat the original test was to use coins to tell the diff ,so for that reason they can use their hand to distinguish between skin and nail like by coins

Comment: I would put the question like: What other communities follow the linked practice?